# Why does range(UserInput).select not work?

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new in VBA and would like to know why the range that user inputs does not work for range().select and if there is another way around this. I have recorded a macro for sorting values and I would like to sort only the values selected by the user.

This is my code for user input:

```
On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Set DataRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
                "Please select range of data.", _
                    Title:="specify range of data to be added", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        If DataRange Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

Dim AnotherDataRange As Range

On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set AnotherDataRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
            "Specify range.", _
                Title:="specify range of req tool for recipes to be added", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    If AnotherDataRange Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

This is the code for the sorter:

```
Sub sorterforrecipe()

    Range(DataRange).Select 'This doesn't work 
    ActiveSheet.sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    AnotherDataRange), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _ 
    xlSortNormal 'This doesn't work as well, where AnotherDataRange is yet another user input
    With ActiveSheet.sort
        .SetRange Range(DataRange) 'This doesn't Work
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

I would like to stress again that it is important that only the range that the user inputs will be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If `DataRange` is **Global** then replace:

```
Range(DataRange).Select
```

with:

```
DataRange.Select
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now, however how do I get the part for AnotherDataRange in: `ActiveSheet.sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    AnotherDataRange), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _ 
    xlSortNormal` to work? I am getting a run-time error "1004"

Comment: @Student1001 I would need to see more of your code/data

Comment: I have updated the code to include the part on AnotherDataRange